# Adjustments when using collections and counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, collections

I'm not as familiar with collections, I have code below that works when reading from a txt file, however I'd like for it to now read from a list.
I've tried changing around "open(a)" however I can't get it to work.
My list is named "cleaned_data" for this example.

```
counts = collections.Counter()
with open(a) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for number in line.split():
            counts.update((number,))
for key, count in counts.items():
    print(f"{key}: x{count}")
```

Comment: you should just be able to get rid of the `with open(a) as infile:` and replace `for line in infile:` with `for line in mylist:`

Comment: That works! However now it counts each element, where I'd like it to count the lines that are identicle. the list it's reading from is a list that is split by delimiter "/" and the data is in separate indices like "ABC", "DEF", etc.

Comment: it sounds like your list is structured differently to a list of lines (which is what you get when iterating through a file in the original code) so you need to adapt either the list or the code accordingly.  maybe show some example data from the list if you still need help with it